# Should I get my leopard gecko a substrate?

Tags: leopard-geckos, substrate

So, I just got a leopard gecko about 4 days ago, it's been years since I got one. I already have a good feeding schedule, he looks happy and healthy and sometimes lets me hold him.

I was chatting online and someone recommended that you should always get a substrate rather than the normal soft hair-mesh that comes with the cage.

He specifically recommended coconut substrates, like this one: [Zoo Med Eco Earth](https://www.amazon.ca/Zoo-Med-Compressed-Coconut-Substrate/dp/B0010OSIHW/ref=asc_df_B0010OSIHW/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=293019554117&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14509978232653157064&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9001021&hvtargid=pla-311753794553&th=1)

So my question is, should I get this for him? Also I have another gecko, under the care of my sibling.

Also if anyone has any extra advice for what to do and what not to do, feel free to post it at the bottom of your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most breeders raise geckos on tissue but it is not very aesthetic. Since the gecko comes from Pakistani countries so relatively desert environments can be reproduced using a clay substrate. There is also the substrate "desert bedding" (LUCKY-REPTILE-Substrat-Desert-Bedding) which is a mix with sand and clay. This substrate is well suited because once well dried it is still compact and the gecko will not eat it and I think it's beautiful in the terrarium. You just have to avoid the fine sand because the gecko risks confusing the sand with calcium and thus eating it to eventually create occlusions

Comment: Well, Id never use sand (Since I have to clean like every other week, and I actually have 4 lizards now, (2 in my cage) 

So I think Ill have to stick with the fabric substrate it came with since nothing sticks to it, and if I wash it, just flinging it around gets all the water out, its a nice little thing. thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I use layers of paper towels as substrate. You just have to make sure you layer them up so the undertank warmer isn’t too hot for them. It’s easy to change out and your gecko can’t ingest it.

Comment: thankfully, him biting the carpet was a temporary problem, we have a slower moving live food (superworms) so he doesnt eat the substrate anymore